# Check if Remote folder exists - Renci.ssh

Tags: c#, ssh

I want to check if a remote folder exists before listing the files inside it.
But this code is giving me `SftpPathNotFoundException : No such file`

I know that the folder that is being checked doesn't exist and thats the reason I would like to handle it.

```
var sftp = new SftpClient(sftpHost, username, password);
string sftpPath30s = "/home/Vendors/clips/1/4/4";

if (sftp.Exists(sftpPath30s))
   {
     var files30s = sftp.ListDirectory(sftpPath30s); //error here
     if(files30s!=null)
       {
          Console.writeline("code doesn't reach here");
       }
   }
```

This code works fine for other existing folders like "/home/Vendors/clips/1/4/3" etc.

Answer (score 2):

the sftp.Exists() method gives you false positive in that case, if it find a part of the directory it echo true even that not all the path is exist.
i would recommend to change you'r code to this:

```
 if (IsDirectoryExist(sftpPath30s))
   {
     var files30s = sftp.ListDirectory(sftpPath30s); 

   }
else
{
     //Do what you want
}
```

and then the method 'IsDirectoryExists':

```
     private bool IsDirectoryExists(string path)
    {
        bool isDirectoryExist = false;

        try
        {
            sftp.ChangeDirectory(path);
            isDirectoryExist = true;
        }
        catch (SftpPathNotFoundException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return isDirectoryExist;
    }
```

dont forget change back the directory you working on in case it metters!

Answer (score 2):

[mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative))

Let's say such a method exist. What then?

```cs
if (sftp.FolderExists(sftpPath30s))
{
   var files30s = sftp.ListDirectory(sftpPath30s);
   if(files30s!=null)
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

Is that Ok?

[Most Certainly Not!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2009/04/27/understanding-the-is-was-and-will-of-programming/)

What happens if between checking if the file exists, and actually getting the file, the file is deleted, or moved?

So you need to write this:

```cs
if (sftp.FolderExists(sftpPath30s))
{
   try
   {
       var files30s = sftp.ListDirectory(sftpPath30s);
       if(files30s!=null)
       {
           ...
       }
   }
   catch (SftpPathNotFoundException) {}
}
```

At which point you don't gain anything from the check. You still have to add a try catch. Instead, it just means you have to do an extra call over the network and make your code more complex. So just do this:

```cs
try
{
   var files30s = sftp.ListDirectory(sftpPath30s);
   if(files30s!=null)
   {
       ...
   }
}
catch (SftpPathNotFoundException) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
string [] seperator = new[] { Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar }
foreach(string dir in destinationFolder.Split(seperator))
    if (!client.Exists(dir))
        client.CreateDirectory(dir);
```